# Python fraction class and menu option

Tags: python, function, class

I am making a class with functions that can be called in a menu option for users to select operations such as add fractions. I am trying to call the functions such as def__add__(self, other) in the menu option but it is not working. How can I call these functions from the class fraction? Is it self.add()?

```
def gcd(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    else:
        return gcd(b % a, a)

c = gcd(15,21)
print (c)

class fraction:
    def __init__ (self, numerator, denominator):
        gcd = hcf(numerator, denominator)
        self.top = numerator/gcd
        self.bottom = denominator/gcd
        
    def __str__(self):
        if self.bottom == 1:
            return str(self.top)
        elif self.top > self.bottom:
           return str(self.top//self.bottom) +str(fraction(self.top % self.bottom,self.bottom ))
        
        else:
            return str(self.top) + "/ " + str(self.bottom)
        
    def __add__(self, other):
        newTop = self.top + other.bottom + other.top * self.bottom 
        newBottom = self.bottom + other.bottom 
        return fraction(newTop, newBottom)
    
    def multiply(self):
        return fraction(2*self.top, self.bottom)
        
    def multiply_by(self, n):
        return fraction(n * self.top, self.bottom)
        
    def __sub__(self,other):
        newTop = self.top - other.bottom - other.top * self.bottom
        newBottom = self.bottom - other.bottom 
        return fraction(newTop, newBottom)
    
    def __mul__(self,other):
        newTop = self.top * other.top
        newBottom = self.bottom * other.bottom
        return fraction(newTop, newBottom)
        
    def __div__(self, other):
        pass
    
    def menu(self):
        print("[1] Add two fractions")
        print("[2] Subtract two fractions")
        print("[3] Multiply two fractions")
        print("[4] Divide two fractions")
        print("[5] Add fraction to integer")
        print("[6] Fraction subtract integer")
        print ("[7] Fraction multiply by integer")
        print ("[8] Fraction divided by integer")
        print("[q] Exit program")
    
    #menu()     
    option = input("Enter your option: ")

    while option!= 'q':
        if option == "1":
          #  a = fraction(15,21)
            self.add(3,4) #call add function
            print("option 1 has been called ")
        elif option == 2:
            #do stuff
            print( "option 2 has been called")
        elif option == 3:
            #do stuff
            print("option 3 has been called")
        elif option ==4:
            #do stuff 
            print("option 4 has been called")
        elif option == 5:
            #do stuff 
            print("option 5 has been called")
        else:
            print("Invalid option")
            
        print()
        menu()
        option = input("Enter your option: ")
        
    
    
a = fraction(4,27)
print(a.multiply())
print(a.multiply_by(7))

print(a + fraction(2,7))
print(fraction(1,2) * fraction(3,7))

`
```

Comment: The `__add__` method is called when you use `+` to add two `fraction` objects. [Similar behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) occurs for `*`, `-`, or `/`. But it looks like there are other bugs in your code. `__init__` should call `gcd`, not `hcf` and the `__add__` and `__sub__` functions are not defined correctly. e.g., `__add__` should have 'newTop = self.top * other.bottom + other.top * self.bottom` and should multiply the denominators.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post what specifically isn't working?

I'm not sure your "add" function is correct (don't you want to add the "tops" and multiply the "bottoms"?), but you just use the "+" sign to use that function, so if you have the right function this should work fine:

```
print(a + fraction(2,7))
```